# Xamarin iOS IPv6 App Store Rejection

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ipv6

We have been building a iOS app that is about Client - Server App.
We are using an SQL connection and WCF web services in the iOS app with Xamarin.

SQL Connection Code :

```
    String ips = "10.0.0.1" ; //Example.
  SqlConnection con =   new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=" + ips + "; initial Catalog="x";user id =y;password = z;");
```

Apple decided to use only ipv6 on iOS9, so they published a document about IPv6 compatibility - [IPv6 Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html)

Xamarin published a blog post about this too - [Making Your iOS Apps IPv6 Ready](https://blog.xamarin.com/making-your-ios-apps-ipv6-ready?utm_content=buffer628cf&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer)

I read all those documents, but I could not manage to get rid of this "Store Rejection" problem.

I want to show you my last attemp : **(ipv4 to ipv6)**

```
string input = "10.0.0.1";
            string ips = "";
            IPAddress address;
            if (IPAddress.TryParse(deviceIP, out address))
            {
                switch (address.AddressFamily)
                {
                    case System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork:
                        // we have IPv4
                        ips = input;
                        break;
                    case System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6:
                        // we have IPv6
                        IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(input).MapToIPv6();
                        ips = "[" + ip.ToString() + "]";
                        break;
                    default:
                        //
                        break;
                }
            }
```

I used the `MapToIPv6()` function as described in the Xamarin blog post, but again my app was rejected by Apple.

Our app works well on IPv4 (Apple says this too). When Apple engineers turn off ipv4 and only use ipv6, our app could not reach the host.

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Platform : Visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin on Windows 10 + Mac OS X El-Capitan

Server : ON IPv4 Only.

Comment: Are you actually using IPv6 addressing as you are showing ipv4 examples?... 10.0.0.1 would be 2002:0a00:0001::0a00:0001 / 0:0:0:0:0:FFFF:0A00:0001 But of course 10.x.x.x are private/internal networks addresses... Can you use a hostname that can be resolved in ipv4 and 6?

Comment: Have you tried it yourself?  Are you sure SQLConnection works with IPv6 addresses?  Finally, connecting directly to a db server from a mobile client is usually considered an **enormous** security risk

Comment: yeap . SQLConncetion suitable with ipv6 as desceribed onmicrosoft document. Our area there is no ipv6 support :)

Comment: @SushiHangover , Yes I convert ipv4 adress to ipv6 address if devices use only ipv6. But did not work :(

Comment: I m still waiting your help ..

Comment: You can't use IP address literals anymore.

Answer (score 3):

There's already some helpful stuff in the comments, but I think that your main problem is that you had the IPv4 to IPv6 mapping the other way around. You were leaving the IPv4 address as it was and mapping the IPv6 address to IPv6 which it already was.

Take a look at the fixed version:

```
string input = "10.0.0.0";
string ips = "";
IPAddress address;
if (IPAddress.TryParse(input, out address))
{
    switch (address.AddressFamily)
    {
        case System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork:
            // we have IPv4, map it to IPv6
            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(input).MapToIPv6();
            ips = ip.ToString();
            break;
        case System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6:
            // we have IPv6, leave it as is
            ips = input;
            break;
    }
}
```

To see for yourself, you can take a look at the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/IPAddress.cs,979b18a883791c0d). From there you see that in your example the `AddressFamily` was `InterNetworkV6` so the `MapToIPv6` method just returns the `IPAddress` unchanged because there's nothing to change.

```
public IPAddress MapToIPv6()
{
    if (AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)
    {
        return this;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: but in your code if device is on IPv4 , then translate input(ipv4) to ipv6 ?  Result [ :::: 10.0.. .. ]

Comment: It's actually not about the device. In the example, we have an IP address `10.0.0.0` which is clearly an IPv4 address. We then create a new instance of `IPAddress` class using the input and check the `AddressFamily` of that IP. So we're not concerned about the device, just the format of our IP address (input). You can take a look at the [IPAddress](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/IPAddress.cs,966bd1c3b2dc55c7) class to see that the `AddressFamily` is defined in the constructor when you create a new instance of that class.

Comment: I think apple IPv6 server cannot reach directly to IPv4 addresses. I  think ips should be convert to ipv6 .  do you agree this ? @hankide.  by the way  Thaks alot

Comment: So my server is on IPv4 (SQL && Web Services). if device on ipv4 , can directly access  . but if device on ipv6 , host ip should be converted to ipv6 . M I right ? @hankide

Comment: If your server has an IPv4 address and you call it directly with that IPv4 address, everything is fine. Because of the changes in iOS9 you should not use the IPv4 format anymore but synthesize it to the IPv6 form. You'll still reach the IPv4 address of your server in the end, but now you're conforming to the requirements set by Apple. Take a look at [this article](http://apple.co/1WmVCdC) for clarification. Especially the part **Use System APIs to Synthesize IPv6 Addresses**.

Comment: Also, see Figure 10-2 in the section **DNS64/NAT64 Transitional Workflow**. It has a nice explanation of how you still reach the IPv4 address even though you start with an IPv6 formatted address.

Comment: :) Yes That is my Problem . Use System APIs to Synthesize IPv6 Addresses. (with Objective C) I can not manage on Xamarin

Comment: Yes, it's also fixed by using the code I provided. Your server can stay happily in the IPv4 world and be still accessible from your app in the future using the synthesized IPv6 address. If you give the code an IPv4 address, it's translated to IPv6 (Apple is happy) and if the address is IPv6 already, everything's good to go. The take away from that is your IPv4 server can stay as it is but your app has to make IPv4 addresses IPv6 somehow. The device itself isn't on IPv4 or IPv6 "mode", that's not what this code is about.

Comment: The **Use System APIs to Synthesize IPv6 Addresses.** example was just to show that what we're doing in the code example (changing IPv4 addresses to IPv6 format) is the same as what Apple tells you to do. That's our C#/Xamarin version of the article, so don't worry about it being Objective-C. We're already handling that stuff ourselves.

Comment: I couldnt manage to Synthesize IPv6 Addresses. MaptoV6 doesnot work.

Comment: That's because you're using it wrong as I told you in my answer and multiple comments. Re-read the thread with thought and you'll find your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Change your server IP: 10.0.0.0 to the domain name, such as db.test.com, it's Apple's recommended approach.

```
string input = "db.test.com";
IPAddress[] ads = Dns.GetHostAddresses (input);
string ips = ads[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have it resolved? You shouldn't care about AddressFamily of device,just care about remote ip AddressFamily .

`IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(input);
Socket s = new Socket (ip.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);`

I used it, and it works.

Comment: Unfortunatelly  unsolved.  I spent 1 week to build iOs application and I spent 4 mounts to solve rejection . But I couldnot solve it :(