# Xamarin iOS (WebClient IPv6 Rejection)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ipv6

My Apple AppStore application was rejected for not supporting IPv6 networks.

Here is declaration of my server URL for WebClient. "ipv4" is IPv4 address of server. I didn't add it here to stay secure.

```
RemoteServerConnector.Instance.DefaultServerUrl = "http://ipv4/api.php";
```

Then I have this method to check connection:

```
   private class MyWebClient : WebClient {

    public int timeOut { get; set; }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address) {
        WebRequest w = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        w.Timeout = timeOut;
        return w;
    }
   }

   public bool checkInternetConnection() {
            try {
                using(MyWebClient client = new MyWebClient()) {
                    client.timeOut = ApiUrls.RemoteServerConnectorTestTimeout;
                    var removeString = "api.php";
                    var testHttp = DefaultServerUrl.EndsWith(removeString) ? DefaultServerUrl.Remove(DefaultServerUrl.Length - removeString.Length, removeString.Length) : DefaultServerUrl;            

                    using(client.OpenRead(testHttp)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            } catch(WebException ex) {
                return ex.Status != WebExceptionStatus.ConnectFailure;
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

It always throw exception in IPv6 networks. I already tried this solution [Xamarin iOS IPv6 App Store Rejection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38621427/xamarin-ios-ipv6-app-store-rejection), but it doesn't work. I also tried to add IPv6 instead of IPv4 in variable DefaultServerUrl. I also tried http://ipv6/api.php and also http://[ipv6]/api.php

Can't find any solution for this type of connection (WebClient). I found only other solutions with TCP/IP protocol and I don't want to change it in my app.

I also saw Xamarin blog about IPv6, but I don't know what to do. Couldn't add link to it, because of permissions.

What should I change in my code to make it working? Thank you for your time :)

Comment: IP addresses are not private information. In any case, you can't use IP address literals.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my WebRequest in Xamarin iOS failing in ipv6 environment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40502766/why-is-my-webrequest-in-xamarin-ios-failing-in-ipv6-environment)

Comment: So, when I replace IP with Hostname, it will work, right?

Comment: I tried to change IP to hostname and still not working. Then I tried to change WebClient to HttpClient (also tried ModernHttpClient). Still not working when testing on IPv6 Network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I tried almost everything and it didn't work I checked settings of customers server. There was not settings for IPv6. We fixed it and now it is working with with ModernHttpClient. I switched in app from IPv4 address to hostname.

My code for ModernHttpClient.

```
                var handler = new NativeMessageHandler();
                using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
                {
                    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(ApiUrls.RemoteServerConnectorTestTimeout);
                    var removeString = "api.php";
                    var testHttp = DefaultServerUrl.EndsWith(removeString) ? DefaultServerUrl.Remove(DefaultServerUrl.Length - removeString.Length, removeString.Length) : DefaultServerUrl;

                    using (client.GetAsync(testHttp).Result)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }

                }
```